# How to use curl in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, hapi

I am new in `NodeJS`, I have a file named "*employe.html*" and I want to use `curl` in this file, so for testing the `curl`
I put following code but it's showing nothing.

Can I use `curl` in this file? If yes then where I am wrong?

Here is my current code:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
    req.write('hello');
  }
  else {
    console.log("Error "+response.statusCode)
    req.write('hellos');
  }
})
```

Comment: What's your problem? can you please elaborate it more? If you getting `html from google` why you need to different logic?

Comment: @narayansharma91: actually if i using above code then existing data not showing means nothing working for me,thats why i am asking where i am wrong ? should i include jquery or javascript file ? because i am working in .html file

Comment: So your this statement ` console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. ` is not working right?

Comment: @narayansharma91: Yes you are right , for testing i using google link, i will replace with my Api link later for fetch data

Comment: Pleas add some more info. BTW to you can use spawning to do this.
Take a look of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229144/streaming-response-from-child-process-spawn-curl-request

spawning new thread have other benefits as well. e.g. you main thread will stay clean code splitting etc.

Comment: @AzeemAslam: actually i just want to fetch data from Api in web so for this i want to use curl , thats it

Comment: do you want to serve html file in response ?
Then you need to check how to serve static files. take a look of this link to serve static files in hapi.

https://github.com/hapijs/inert

leme know if it resolves your problem.

Comment: If you want to host static file leme know I will help you in adding script.
That way your html file will not render in browser.
BR,

Comment: @AzeemAslam: yes i just want to get response from Api using curl

Comment: Look if you just want to serve html file content to browser then you don't need curl for that. All Node HTTP frameworks support to serve static files I have shared an example kindly give it a try and if you have some query feel free to ask. :)

Comment: @nishasehgal: I am confused a little. You are using `Node.js` code inside a .html file. How? To get a response from an API in an HTML file, you can just use jQuery AJAX. curl is generally used from command lines/shells. It is much simpler to use $.get (jQuery AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to serve static html file in hapi in your case `employe.html` to `path='<domain name | localhost>/'` or root of your site. you just need to fix path to html file according to your directory structure.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({port: 9200});


server.register(Inert, (err) => {

if (err) {
    throw err;
}

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.file('/res/html/employe.html');
    }
});
server.route({
    path: "/res/{path*}",
    method: "GET",
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: "./res",
            listing: false,
            index: false
        }
    }});


});
server.start();
```